# Hibernate: number of batches

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, jpql

The maximum number of packages is specified in the settings.

```
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size
```

*Is it possible to find out how many batches (and what size) were used for any database operation while the program was running?*

In particular, I am interested in JPQL.

Is it possible to find out?

Comment: What do you mean with "number of buckets"?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the question

Answer (score 0):

if you have session object access in java code you use

- session.getJdbcBatchSize()

to get batch size.